# Error Cloning a Git repository on my mainframe USS folder

Tags: mainframe

We have the Rocket Git port (Git 2.14.4 for z/OS) installed on our mainframe and I have a git repository in my mainframe USS folder. I am trying to clone that to my windows workstation.

I gave the following command in my local git bash

git clone usrid@host-url:/u/usrid/mainfolder/repo.git/

This initially prompts for my host password. Once that is provided, it proceeds with the clone but ends up with the following error. It looks like i am missing some kind of environment variable. I would appreciate any pointers.

`git-upload-pack: FSUM7351 not found fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists`

Comment: @Hogstrom , @ phd asked me delete my original question and repost it and invite you to answer. Please post your response and i will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you are running on z/OS the Rocket Git client has limitations per Rocket's [documentation](https://my.rocketsoftware.com/RocketCommunity). Note: you need to register to access the downloads (it's free but requires registration nonetheless).  I've included a snippet from the install PDF on their website.

**Restrictions**

- Some files used by Git must be encoded and tagged as ISO8859-1. These
  include:

  - Git attribute files, whether in .git/info/attributes or .gitattributes
  - .gitignore files
- The only remote protocols supported are ssh and https.
- **Only client mode is supported; in other words, Git for z/OS can clone from, and push to, remote repositories via ssh or https, but cannot be the target of clone and push from other clients.**
- The only encodings supported for git-encoding are ISO8859-1 and UTF-8. The only encodings fully supported for zos-working-tree-encoding are ISO8859-1, IBM-1047 and UTF-8.

At this time the Git Client for z/OS does not support z/OS as being targeted by clients.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify in your command where `git-upload-pack` is on OMVS (it is in your git bin directory) by using  `-u`, `--upload-pack <path>` path to `git-upload-pack` on the `remote`, you can override the `Rocket` restriction and use `ZOS` as a git server.

But then you will be on an officially unsupported mode.